# SQLite: set quote character exporting CSV

Tags: quoting, sqlite

I have a SQL database. If I export it as CSV using `sqlitebrowser` there is an option to define a "Quote character". How can I set the quote character when doing the export with a script? The default is `"` and want it to be `@`.

Export script without quote-character definition:

```
sqlite3 my.db<<EOF
.mode csv
.separator |
.output out.csv
SELECT * FROM myTable
EOF
```

Desired output:

```
@This is@|@ a
"table" with@|@ three columns, @
@ some
newlines,
and...
@|@two@|@ "rows". @
```

I've looked in the documentation und couldn't find such an option. Does it exist?

Comment: Are the quotes part of the data in the table?

Comment: @Kusalananda There are no @ in the table

Comment: What about double quotes?  I'm trying to understand whether it's something that is in the database that you can perform a simple substitution on, or whether it's something that the client/database is adding that you may change.

Comment: @Kusalananda There are double quotes \", but I don't want to escape them. I'd prefer to use another quote character which is not used in the table.

Comment: should the "a" in the first line have a trailing `@`?

Comment: @JeffSchaller: It appears to me that the OP is presenting a single "row" of their ```myTable``` table, in which the value in the second column contains a newline.

Comment: @JeffSchaller : G-Man is right, I've added a second row to make it clearer.